# Mysql Replication SLAVE go down

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have a problem with mysql replication.

I configure two virtual host.

Server 1 Apache + mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.41-MariaDB

Master and SLAVE OF Server2

Server 2 mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.42

Master and SLAVE OF Server1

Topologi MASTER + MASTER

When I restart slaves all work good, short latency and fast update. But when I wait a few minutes the replication not work more. If I update some row or make a insert or delete the slave not update the changes.

The logs not write any error, but the master_position_log is diferent between master and slave.

And if I restart the slaves all works again, the bdd is updated and the replication works well.

I don't know what happen, seems the threads sleep or death.

Thanks for some idea for fix the problem

In two cases the processes seems ok.

SERVER1

Kill    168 system user     None    Connect 1146    Waiting for master to send event    ---

Kill    169 system user     None    Connect 945 Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it ---

Kill    170 master  XXXXXXX:59273   None    Binlog Dump 1145    Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated   ---

SERVER2

Kill    73  root    XXXXXX:55089    None    Binlog Dump 1137    Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated   ---

Kill    76  system user     None    Connect 1137    Waiting for master to send event    ---

Kill    77  system user     None    Connect 985 Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it ---

Comment: Download nmon http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php (or use your own favourite tool) to see if you have any bottle necks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is latency.

My solution, create a CRON every minut for stop and start slave.

Now all works.

Cristian

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
```

on each server.  That is likely to tell you what is wrong.

You *do* understand the potential problems with `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `UNIQUE` keys when you are writing to both heads of a dual-Master topology?